# How to store random data created in r for further use?

Tags: r

I am using Rstudio and I created a random data like this:

```
n<-500
u<-runif(n)
```

This data is now stored but obviously once I run the code again it will change. How could I store it to use it again? If the number of points was small I would just define a vector and manually write the numbers like

```
DATA<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

But obviously doing this for 500 points is not very practical. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such cases, i.e. when using pseudo random number generators, a common approach is to set the seed:

```
set.seed(12345)
```

You have to store the seed that you used for the simulation, so that in future you's set the same seed and get the same sequence of numbers. The seed indicates that the numbers are not truly random, they're pesudo random. The same seed will generate the same numbers. There are services such as [RANDOM](https://www.random.org/) which attempt to generate true random numbers.

Comment: thanks, but even after reading the help section on set.seed I am not sure how to approach it. How would I actually use it for my case? Never mind i got it. Thank You.

Comment: Do the maintainers of R guarantee that the implementation of `runif` or the underlying (default?) RNG will be stable over time and on different platforms? If not, and if you really only want to store 500 points and are very paranoid, it's probably a lot more future-proof to save the vector `u` itself to disk (either in a text file, or in R's `.rds` format, etc.) than to rely on the same seed giving you the same result everywhere and forever.

Comment: @ChrisHaug RNG implementations are not truly platform independent. Some people even store the hardware an analysis was run on in order to ensure reproducibility.